# Actualizar tablas relacionadas laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

llevo un rato mirando la documentacion y creo que esta correcto, sin embargo no me funciona como es debido, en vez de actualizarme, me crea un registro.

El tema es el siguiente. Tengo una tabla con vendedores y otras con productos, la idea es actualizar un producto de un determinado vendedor.

Estos son los datos.

La ruta

```
Route::resource('vendedor.producto', 'vendedor\vendedorProductoController',['except' => ['create','show','edit']]);
```

y la estructura de la ruta cuando la ponemos en el navegador viene a ser asi.

```
vendedor/{vendedor}/producto/{producto}
```

En mi caso por ejemplo seria algo asi

```
vendedor/95/producto/100
```

lo cual seria que del vendedor 95 actualize el producto 100

el modelo vendedor

```
class vendedor extends User
{


    protected $table = 'vendedores';



    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\modelos\producto');
    }
}
```

el modelo productos

```
    class producto extends Model
    {
       use SoftDeletes;

       protected $table = 'productos';

       protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

       protected $hidden = ['pivot','deleted_at'];

       const PRODUCTO_DISPONIBLE = 'disponible';
       const PRODUCTO_NODISPONIBLE = 'no_disponible';

       protected $fillable = ['nombre','descripcion','cantidad','status','imagen','vendedor_id'];

       public function estaDisponible()
       {
         return $this->status == product::PRODUCTO_DISPONIBLE;
       }

       public function categorias()
       {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\modelos\categoria');
        }

       public function vendedor()
       {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\modelos\vendedor');
       }

       public function transacciones()
       {
          return $this->hasMany('App\modelos\transaccion');
       }

}
```

El controlador con el metodo update

```
public function update(Request $request, $idvendedor)
    {
        $vendedor = vendedor::findorfail($idvendedor);


        $datos = [
            'nombre' => $request->nombre,
            'descripcion' => $request->descripcion,
            'cantidad' => $request->cantidad,
            'imagen' => '1.jpg',
           'vendedor_id' => $vendedor->id,

                ];
        $producto =new producto($datos);


        $vendedor->productos()->save($producto);



    }
```

Pues bien, no lo actualiza, simplemente crea un registro nuevo como si fuera el metodo store

----------------EDICION1--------------------------------------------------------

He hecho unas modificaciones al codigo y sigue sin funcionar.

Pongo las modificaciones

```
public function update(Request $request, $idvendedor,$idproducto)
    {
        $vendedor = vendedor::findorfail($idvendedor);
        $producto = producto::findorfail($idproducto);


        //$producto = new producto();

        $producto->nombre = $request->nombre;
        $producto->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
        $producto->cantidad = $request->cantidad;
        $producto->imagen ='9999.jpg';
        $producto->vendedor_id = $vendedor->id;


        $vendedor->productos()->save();


    }
```

En teoria tiene que funcionar con esta linea

```
$producto = producto::findorfail($idproducto);
```

en vez de esta

```
 //$producto = new producto()
```

pero la he comentado simplemente para que veais que he usado las dos opciones y no me funciona, el error que me da es este

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
```

Y aqui estan la migracion por si aclara algo

MIGRACION PRODUCTO

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->integer('cantidad')->unsigned();
          $table->string('imagen');
            $table->integer('vendedor_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->foreign('vendedor_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de las tablas?
Estas creando un nuevo producto en el método update() de tu controlador, se ve muy claro. No veo que te hayas traido un producto y lo cambies antes de guardarlo, solo lo creas. ¿Y la id del producto a modificar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que te muestra actualmente es porque te falta el parámetro de entrada: Para que funcione el método save en una relación, debes poner el modelo que deseas salvar como parámetro de entrada, SIN EMBARGO esto no va a actualizar el registro, esto va a crear uno nuevo:

```
    $vendedor = vendedor::findOrFail($idvendedor);
    $producto = producto::findOrFail($idproducto);

    $producto->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $producto->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $producto->cantidad = $request->cantidad;
    $producto->imagen ='9999.jpg';
    $producto->vendedor_id = $vendedor->id;

    // para agregar un nuevo modelo a la relación, es necesario pasarlo como parámetro en save
    $vendedor->productos()->save($producto);
```

**Solución al problema de actualizar un producto**:

Tu problema real es no poder actualizar un determinado producto para un determinado vendedor, sin embargo, la llave principal del modelo Producto es su id, por lo cual no necesitas en lo más mínimo (en este caso) el id del vendedor para actualizar el producto:

```
    $vendedor = vendedor::findOrFail($idvendedor);
    $producto = producto::findOrFail($idproducto);

    // nuevos valores...
    $producto->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $producto->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $producto->cantidad = $request->cantidad;
    $producto->imagen ='9999.jpg';
    $producto->vendedor_id = $vendedor->id;

    // guardar producto
    $producto->save();
```

Comment: Siento la tardanza en responder, La solucion funcionó perfectamente y la respuesta muy aclaratoria. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentarlo de la siguiente forma y verifica que el `$idvendedor` si este llegando

```
$vendedor = vendedor::findOrFail($idvendedor);

$producto = new producto();

$producto->nombre = $request->nombre;

$producto->descripcion = $request->descripcion;

$producto->cantidad = $request->cantidad;

$producto->imagen = '1.jpg';

$producto->vendedor_id = $vendedor->id;

$vendedor->productos()->save();
```

Comment: He probado  esa solucion  y me da el error que comento arriba

Answer (score 1):

Buenas:
Si quieres que se te actualize, en vez de utilizar

```
$producto = new producto();
$vendedor->productos()->save($producto);
```

¿Por que no utilizas?

```
use App\Producto;
....
$producto = Producto::where('vendedor_id', '=', $vendedor->id)->first();
$producto->save();
```

Porque por lo que entiendo, solo quieres actualizar **un** producto determinado de **un** determinado vendedor ¿no?

Comment: Esta es una solucion que no habia pensado y me parece interesante no obstante la he estado probando y tal y como esta no funciona correctamente, ya que exactamente quiero actualizar 1 producto de 1 vendedor pero el vendedor puede tener mas de 1 producto, tal y como esta planteado busca el primer producto  de un vendedor en concreto y no es eso, tiene que buscar el producto que le especificamos no el primero en orden de id. Lo he intentado adaptar con otro where y me da fallos al salvar, no obstante seguiré probando me parece interesante. Gracias.